# Suggestion popup to wrong spelled word in Swing application

Tags: java, spell-checking

I am web developer and don't have much knowledge about swing applications.

I am doing a desktop application, in that I need to give a suggestion popup to wrongly spelled words. Please someone specify any sample code for that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you assume an Internet connection is available, or do you need a local dictionary?

Comment: Do you need assistance with spell-checking or with displaying the popup? What have you tried?

Comment: I am not using any internet connection. All the details are saved in a .str document. On Click for a check it will give the words in red underline which is wrong spell, then on click on that word i need to show suggestion to it.

Comment: [Take this visual guide to Java Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/features/components.html) as tutorial, and if you still have question after working on that explain in more detail, where you have problems.

Answer (score 0):

- Proprietary: [Wintertree](http://www.wintertree-software.com/dev/ssce/javasdk.html)
- Open Source: [JOrtho](http://jortho.sourceforge.net/)

Check the project sites for examples and documentation.